# Dealing with subtypes and supertypes in Database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key, subtypes

I'm currently doing a database project for a class and I am having some difficulty dealing the subtypes and supertypes.
This is the list of entities and their attributes:

```
Piece (PIECE_ID, Description) 
   In_house (PIECE_ID)
      Bulk (PIECE_ID, Location)
      To order (PIECE_ID, Lead time) 
   Purchased (PIECE_ID, Cost)
Order (OID, Order date)
Supplier (SID, Name, Postcode, City )
Supplier piece (SPID, Price, description)
```

To clarify, Piece is the supertype with two subtypes, In_house and Purchased. In_house then has two subtypes, Bulk and To Order.

My first instinct was to keep a table Piece(PIECE_ID, description), another one for Purchased(PIECE_ID, cost), and then delete the In_house one and keep only the subtypes as Bulk(PIECE_ID, Location) and To_order(PIECE_ID, Lead Time).

First question: is this better as opposed to keeping the In_house table and put the Bulk and To_order info all in that table, generating some NULL values?

Also, how does the system know that there can't be any repeated PIECE_ID in the Purchased,  Bulk and To_order tables? Do I need to create a separate ID for these individual tables or can they just the foreign key for the Piece table?

Finally, the Purchased table has a 1:N obligatory on both relationship with Supplier part table. Therefore, I have to put the primary key of the Purchased table in the Supplier piece table. If the primary key on Purchased is just PIECE_ID, how can it associate that those PIECE_ID are from the Purchased table and not from the other tables that have PIECE_ID as a primary key?

Please let me know in comments if clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand all of your questions, but one fairly common model for super/sub-type is to add a classifier attribute to your supertype:

```
CREATE TABLE super
( xxx_id ... not null primary key
, classifier int not null
,   unique (classifier, xxx_id)
,   check (classifier in (1,2,...))
)

CREATE TABLE sub1
( xxx_id ... not null primary key
, classifier int default 1 not null
,    check (classifier = 1)
,     foreign key (classifier,xxx_id)
          references super (classifier,xxx_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sub2
( xxx_id ... not null primary key
, classifier int default 2 not null
,    check (classifier = 2)
,     foreign key (classifier,xxx_id)
          references super (classifier,xxx_id)
)
```

Now the classifier in super guarantees that for example 1 can't be located in sub2 (that it exist in any subtype is handled by a transaction).

However, this model is not fully practical if the classifier changes, so this is more of a food for thought answer (but it is too long to be a comment).

Answer (score 0):

An important deciding factor would be business preference for performance vs code complexity.

If performance is critical, then code-complexity takes a back seat.  In this case, you probably want to ensure you look at keeping critical rows as compact as possible, by not having little-used columns in the main table.

If code-simplicity is deemed of paramount importance, performance takes a back seat, allowing a much wider range of possibilities.

SQL Server has a little-implemented feature know as [Sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns) that allow columns with a large ratio of null-to-non-null values to be more storage-efficient.  So, if 90% of pieces are "in-house", then you can add sparse columns for the 10% that are "purchased" to the main table, and not really worry too much about the performance impact of reading those rows, while ensuring all those NULL values are as space-efficient as possible.

As is normally the case, the devil is in the details, and vastly dependent on the requirements for the specific business.